# Using double curly Vue.js braces inside php string param

Tags: php, vue.js

So I'm in the middle of mixing `Vue.js`, `PHP` & `HTML` and I'm running into a small issue - I have the following HTML section:

```
<button class="task button is-fullwidth is-flex" v-for="task, taskid in list.list">
    <span class="icon">
        <img src="<?= Path::o365("{{task.title}}" . '.svg'); ?>" />
    </span>
    <span class="task__handle">{{task.title}}</span>
</button>
```

Now everything works great except calling the `Vue.js` title inside the `PHP` code.. I have the following:

```
<img src="<?= Path::o365("{{task.title}}" . '.svg'); ?>" />
```

Is it possible to invoke double curly braces inside a PHP param? I have the HTML version (`<span class="task__handle">{{task.title}}</span>`) working perfectly fine.

All help is appreciated! I don't even know if this is possible, so I'll be learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Techincally you can't.

But if what `Path::o365()` does is to convert a resource name into a url, you can make a workaround like this:

```
<img :src="`<?= Path::o365('${task.title}' . '.svg'); ?>'`" />
```

This will eventually resolves into something like this:

```
<img :src="`https://example.com/images/${task.title}.svg`" />
```

Which is actually a legit javascript string literal and also refers to the variable `task.title`

Comment: Wow, didn't know that but it actually worked! I'll have to do more research into this, but it's pulling in the correct SVG as needed. Upvoted.